# How to list All the labels present in term from the term store share point online

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom

I am using following code get all the terms using GUID.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStore = session.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var parentTermId = '894e81d3-c0d5-477d-952f-582ba564fa1b'; //parent Term Id
var parentTerm = termStore.getTerm(parentTermId);
var terms = parentTerm.get_terms();  //load child Terms
context.load(terms, 'Include(IsRoot, Labels, TermsCount, CustomSortOrder, Id, IsAvailableForTagging, Name, PathOfTerm, Parent, TermSet.Name)');
context.executeQueryAsync(
function(){
   //print child Terms
   for(var i = 0; i < terms.get_count();i++){

    var term = terms.getItemAtIndex(i);
    var term_name = term.get_name();
    var term_parent = term.get_parent();
    var terms_count = term.get_termsCount();
    }
  }, function(sender,args){
   console.log(args.get_message());    
 });
```

Presently I am getting the term count property properly. I want to list out all the labels present inside the term.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to list out all the labels present inside the term.

[`SP.Taxonomy.Term.labels` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312599.aspx)  - gets a collection of Label objects for the current Term object.

In your example labels could be printed like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < terms.get_count();i++){
   var term = terms.getItemAtIndex(i);
   //...

   //print labels of term  
   term.get_labels().get_data().forEach(function(lbl){
      console.log(lbl.get_value());     
   });
}
```

Comment: Dear Vadim, I am looking for something like following code                           
 var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
        var termOrder = currentTerm.get_customSortOrder();
  var orders = termOrder.split(':');
        for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
           var key = orders[i]; // key is the term Guid
               // do something, you're looping through children in the correct Custom Sort Order
           } Here, I am able to get the GUID of the labels. How to get the name of the labels?